# Hibernate generate sql query missing "(" character

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I faced an issue when I use @Query

```
    @Query(value = "select c.id as id, c.store_id as store_id, c.name as name, c.type as type, c.rate as rate, " +
        "(select count(pc.partner_id) from partner_commission pc where pc.commission_id = c.id) as number_of_partner " +
        "from commission c join partner_commission pc on c.id = pc.commission_id where c.store_id=:storeId", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Commission> findCommissionForManagement(@Param("storeId") Long storeId, Pageable pageable);
```

I already tested this script on database (postgresql), it worked! But, the sql script generated by hibernate as below:

```
Hibernate: select c.id as id, c.store_id as store_id, c.name as name, c.type as type, c.rate as rate, (select count(pc.partner_id) from partner_commission pc where pc.commission_id = c.id) as number_of_partner from commission c join partner_commission pc on c.id = pc.commission_id where c.store_id=? limit ?
Hibernate: select count(pc) from partner_commission pc where pc.commission_id = c.id) as number_of_partner from commission c join partner_commission pc on c.id = pc.commission_id where c.store_id=?
2021-08-16 04:05:44.645  WARN 15976 --- [llCommissions-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
2021-08-16 04:05:44.645 ERROR 15976 --- [llCommissions-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
  Position: 74
```

I hope to get some help

Answer (score 0):

It seems like @Query has broken up the subquery incorrectly. Can you restructure the query using Joins?

Here is my suggestions, not tested but I hope you can debug it further to get your desired result.

```sql
SELECT
    c.id AS id,
    c.store_id AS store_id,
    c.name AS name,
    c.type AS type,
    c.rate AS rate
    pc.count AS number_of_partner
FROM
    commission c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        id,
        COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM
        partner_commission
    GROUP BY
        partner_commission.id
) AS pc
ON pc.id = c.store_id
WHERE
    c.store_id = :storeId
```

Comment: It's totally OK.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a Spring Data JPA bug. You can try to workaround this by providing a custom count query in the `@Query` annotation.